# Is it appropriate to use a softmax activation with a categorical crossentropy loss?

Tags: binary-classification, sigmoid, softmax, categorical-crossentropy, binary-crossentropy

I have a binary classification problem where I have 2 classes. A sample is either class 1 or class 2 - For simplicity, lets say they are exclusive from one another so it is definitely one or the other.

For this reason, in my neural network, I have specified a softmax activation in the last layer with 2 outputs and a categorical crossentropy for the loss. Using tensorflow:

```
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, input_shape=(100,), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here are my questions.

1. If the sigmoid is equivalent to the softmax, firstly is it valid to specify 2 units with a softmax and categorical_crossentropy?
2. Is it the same as using binary_crossentropy (*in this particular use case*) with 2 classes and a sigmoid activation, and if so why?

I know that for non-exclusive multi-label problems with more than 2 classes, a binary_crossentropy with a sigmoid activation is used, why is the non-exclusivity about the multi-label case uniquely different from a binary classification with 2 classes only, with 1 (class 0 or class 1) output and a sigmoid with binary_crossentropy loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first recap the definition of the **binary cross-entropy (BCE)** and the **categorical cross-entropy (CCE)**.

Here's the **BCE** ([equation 4.90 from this book](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf#page=226))

$$-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left( t_{n} \ln y_{n}+\left(1-t_{n}\right) \ln \left(1-y_{n}\right)\right) \label{1}\tag{1},$$

where

- $t_{n} \in\{0,1\}$ is the target
- $y_n \in [0, 1]$ is the prediction (as produced by the *sigmoid*), so $1 - y_n$ is the probability that $n$ belongs to the other class

Here's the **CCE** ([equation 4.108](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf#page=229))

$$
-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{K} t_{n k} \ln y_{n k}\label{2}\tag{2},
$$
where

- $t_{n k} = \{0, 1\}$ is the target of input $n$ for class $k$, i.e. it's $1$ when $n$ is labelled as $k$ and $0$ otherwise (so it's $0$ for all $K$ except for one of them)
- $y_{n k}$ is the probability that $n$ belongs to the class $k$, as produced by the *softmax* function

Let $K=2$. Then equation \ref{2} becomes

$$
-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{2} t_{n k} \ln y_{n k} =
-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left( t_{n 1} \ln y_{n 1} + t_{n 2} \ln y_{n 2} \right)
\label{3}\tag{3} 
$$

So, if $[y_{n 1},  y_{n 2}]$ is a [probability vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_vector) (which is the case if you use the softmax as the activation function of the last layer), then, *in theory*, the BCE and CCE are equivalent in the case of **binary classification**. *In practice*, if you are using TensorFlow, to choose the most suitable loss function for your problem, you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47034889/3924118).

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much!